# Ошибка Kotlin not configured в Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

Все зависимости автоматически подключены после создания KotlinActivity. Но висит ошибка Kotlin not configured. После перезагрузки студии появилась еще одна ошибка: Plugin Error: Kotlin threw an uncaught IncorrectOperationException.

**build.gradle(Project)**

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4-3'
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle(Module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
}
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.alex.tutorials"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

           testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
}
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: для проекта на котлин в версии Android Studio меньше 3.0 нужно [несколько больше действий](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-android.html), вы их выполняли

Comment: Все как описано сделано. Раньше так же подключал и не было ошибок.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы путаете теплое с мягким. Все настройки в `build.gradle` влияют на процесс сборки проекта, который можно запустить и из командной строки, без IDE.

Android Studio же использует систему плагинов, и вот как раз тут у вас что-то не работает или не настроено как надо. Переустановите ее или только плагин Kotlin, сам проект к ошибкам студии имеет только косвенное отношение.